# Are pumps used in geothermal systems?

Tags: geology, temperature, geothermal-heat, earth-system

The water held underground in a geothermal system is under high temperature and pressure. Are pumps used to raise the very hot underground water to the surface or does the water rise under its own pressure? One source says that the water is pumped up[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://energy.gov/eere/geothermal/electricity-generation) while another says that it rises on its own[<sup>[2]</sup>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjpp2MQffnw). I am not sure if I just misunderstand the wording. Does anyone know which is correct?

[1]: [energy.gov/eere/geothermal/electricity-generation](https://energy.gov/eere/geothermal/electricity-generation)

[2]: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjpp2MQffnw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjpp2MQffnw)

Comment: There are several different types of geothermal systems, dry steam, flash, binary, or even just geothermal heating. each varies in how they use pumps.

Answer (score 1):

Pumped systems are much more common. However, there are some artesian type hot springs where the water flows spontaneously and is not replenished in the immediate area.

Comment: [Image here.](http://energy-alaska.wikidot.com/geothermal)